# How can I check multiple search id's in a pivot table

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I would like to have a search page where you can give a input of multiple ingredients and gives only output of recipes that has all the given ingredients. I save the ingredients of a recipe in a pivot table ingredient_recipe with ingredient_id and recipe_id. Can someone help me how to make this query?

So the pivot table is like this:

```
| id | ingredient_id | recipe_id |
| 1  | 1             | 1         |
| 2  | 2             | 1         |
| 3  | 1             | 2         |
| 4  | 2             | 3         |
```

So if I search to a recipe with ingredients with id = 1 and id = 2 only recipe with id = 1 have to be the output. Because recipe with id 2 and 3 have only one of the two ingredients.

```
$recipes_with_ingredient1 = DB::table('ingredient_recipe') >where('ingredient_id', $ingredient_id)->pluck('recipe_id');
       
$recipes_with_ingredient2 = DB::table('ingredient_recipe')->where('ingredient_id', 2)->pluck('recipe_id');

$result=array_intersect($recipes_with_ingredient1,$recipes_with_ingredient1);
```

But this gives an error: array_intersect(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array

Comment: Since you're using Laravel, do you have models and relationships setup? Also, have you tried anything? Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service, and we're happy to help you, but it's expected you make an attempt first so we're not trying things you've already done.

Comment: A) Your solution should not be posted in the question, there's an answers section below, please post it there. B) your solution is not great... What if you select a 3rd or 4th ingredient? You'd need variables for all of them. C) You're not using Models and Relationships; why? This should be as simple as `$recipes = Recipe::query(); foreach($request->input('ingredient_ids') as $ingredientId) { $recipes = $recipes->whereHas(['ingredients' => function ($query) use ($ingredientId) { return $query->where('id', $ingredientId); })]); } $recipes = $recipes->get();`.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to remove the relevant part and replace it with "Problem Solved". If you solved the question, you should add it as an answer. Stack Overflow is not just a problem-solving service, it is a Q&A library for all users, so if someone else has the same issue they can find the answer here too.